# How does the ISNULL function in SQL Server evaluate its passed in parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was trying to figure out a work around to not use a case statement when a first and last name was null in a stored procedure I am trying to create and tried `ISNULL(@lastName + ', ' ,'')`. I got a unexpected result, I thought it would always return `User's name: ,` when a null value is passed in because I am adding `', '` to the passed in null value in the parameters.

```
DECLARE @lastName VARCHAR(30), @firstName VARCHAR(30);

SET @lastName = NULL;
SET @firstName = NULL;

SELECT 'User''s name: ' + ISNULL(@lastName + ', ' ,'') + ISNULL(@firstName + ' ', '');
```

**Result**

```
User's name:
```

The above result is the result I am looking for; however, the expected result I though would be:

**Expected Result**

```
User's name: ,
```

I think it is awesome that this worked. However, I would like to get a better understand of why it worked.

How does the `ISNULL` function evaluating its passed in parameters?

Comment: Any time you attempt to concatenate a NULL string with any other string, the result is null. When a variable (or column) is null, then <variable> + ', ' returns NULL. That is the actual value that ISNULL evaluates first. Since it is null, the 2nd argument is returned. And note - case **EXPRESSION** not statement. Those are very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really isn't about `ISNULL()` (and I would generally recommend using the standard `COALESCE()` instead).

`+` operator returns `NULL` if either argument is `NULL`.

So:

```
ISNULL(NULL + ', ', '')
```

returns an empty string `''` because the first argument is `NULL`.

Note that `COALESCE()` would behave the same way.

Answer (score 3):

It is not about `ISNULL()`, it is about string concatenation operator `+`. When one of its arguments is `null`, this operator yields `null`.

*If* you want a different behavior, you can use `concat()`, which allows concatenating `null` with a non-`null` value, returning the non-`null` value as a result.

```
select null + ',' null_plus, concat(null, ',') null_concat
GO
```

```
null_plus | null_concat
:-------- | :----------
null      | ,
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1969b107f5d84b9ee09d66e4b52ed1a0)**

Answer (score 2):

use `coalesce`  function

> Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the
>   first expression that initially doesn't evaluate to NULL. For example,
>   SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, 'third_value', 'fourth_value'); returns
>   the third value because the third value is the first value that isn't
>   null.

```
DECLARE @lastName VARCHAR(30), @firstName VARCHAR(30);

SET @lastName = NULL;
SET @firstName = NULL;

SELECT 'User''s name: ' + coalesce(@lastName + ', ' + @firstName,@lastname,'')
```

Comment: Why did you use ISNULL here? You should just use the empty string as a third parameter to coalesce. coalesce(lastName + ', ' + firstName, lastname, '')

Answer (score 0):

How isnull works, well it will only evaluate if the the given value or result is a null value or not, as the variable is null, even if you use "+','", it will still evaluate to null as the variable is null.

I think for your example you are missing an apostrophe or maybe when posted the question it was deleted, but the below is the same as yours but works and gives the value you expect.

[W3Schools May provide more details](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_isnull.asp)

DECLARE @lastName VARCHAR(30), @firstName VARCHAR(30);

SET @lastName = NULL;
SET @firstName = NULL;

SELECT 'User''s name: ' + ISNULL(@lastName + ', ' ,'') + ISNULL(@firstName + ' ', '');